# Why is an imported plot different from the saved one?

Tags: graphics

I have a question concerning the importing of previously saved graphics. So I drew a plot in Mathematica and saved it by right clicking on it and saving it ("save as..."). When I open this (.pdf) saved graphics in my pdf viewer, everything seems in order. Only when I try to import it back into Mathematica, two of the plot's lines cross over the plot frame. You will at once see what I mean, when you see the picture: [image: picture].

On the left is the saved plot opened in Sumatra viewer, right is the very same plot imported into Mathematica. You can see that the names of the files are identical. Why, then, the plot lines go over the frame?

Comment: Mathematica's PDF import capabilities are rather limited.  Here it is ignoring the clipping masks. So what can you do in practice?  First, realize that many (most?) complex PDFs just won't be imported perfectly, if at all.  However, you can reprocess (re-save) PDFs with various tools (Ghostscript, muPDF, etc.) and convert them to earlier version PDF specifications, then see if that helps.  This is what I am doing in [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) (check the source) before I can at all import LaTeX-generated PDFs with any reliability. I also had good luck with ...

Comment: ... using OS X's Preview app to re-save PDFs.  But once again: in general don't expect great results for arbitrary PDFs.  In this case at least it imported without artefacts ...

Comment: Had the same issue on 10.1, Win7 64bit (perhaps you can add your version and OS, too). Only (suboptimal) workaround for me was to export as bitmap.